# iOS S3 SDK: How to putObject as world readable

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

Using the AWS SDK for iOS, I can upload a file to a bucket like so:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:key inBucket:bucket];
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:file];
por.contentLength = file.length;
por.stream = stream;
[s3 putObject:por];
```

This works fine, but the file is marked Read/Write Owner. I'd like the file to be Read World, Write Owner. How can you specify read permissions for an object when putting it to S3?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have to set the bucket itself as world readable. That's what I do.